# Unable to connect remotely to oracle database with android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to access my oracle 10g database which is in my laptop. I am  using android program to access it. 
I have added ojdbc14.jar file in referenced libraries in eclipse and I am unable to run the app(app is not being built). I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me? Tell me a method to do it.
I am new to android and java.
Before adding ojdbc14.jar file in referenced libraries my app was being built and run in my phone. But i was not able to connect with database as ***tv.append("\n1")*** was not being executed

```js
        package oracle.connect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;   
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Try extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button connectWith;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    connectWith = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGetValue);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCheck);
    connectWith.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.bGetValue: {
        try {
            tv.setText("hello");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            tv.append("\n1");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@my laptop ip:1521:XE", "Aakash",
                    "aakash");
            PreparedStatement st = con
                    .prepareStatement("select id from new where username='Aakash'");
            int i = st.executeUpdate();
            if (i == 1) {
                tv.setText("Success");
            } else {
                tv.setText("fail");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        break;// case closed
    }// switch over
    }
    }
```

The error which i get in console

```
 Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
  #
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
       #
  #  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:124), pid=6836, tid=936
  #  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
  #
  # JRE version:  (8.0_05-b13) (build )
  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed       oops)
  # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
  #
  # An error report file with more information is saved as:
  # D:\SDK files for eclipse1\Try1\hs_err_pid6836.log
  #
  # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
  #
```

Comment: Does your laptop run android?  Are you running it on an emulator?  If not, why do you think it would work?  It looks like you're trying to run android code as a java program?  That's nowhere near right.

Comment: No, i m running android app on Phone

Comment: Thanks, by mistake i selected java.

Comment: But as selecting android i cannot access database

Comment: You may want to try to use Java 7 on your development machine.

Comment: @Henry , I complied it using java application.. Now when i compile by adding ojdbc14.jar i get unhandled event loop exception and i have to restart my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as an Android project:

```
Run As -> Android Application
```

The error you reported has nothing to do with connecting to Oracle.

Comment: i m running it as a android application. I have 1 reputation else i would have posted picture of that